# Instead of half-life would exp-life be easier to calculate?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Specifically if we know how long it takes $t_0$ for $\frac{1}{e}$ of the principle amount and we know the principle amount we would be able to form the exponential equation $P_{0}e^{rt}$ where $t_{0}r=-\ln(e)=-1$. Just a thought I had while teaching was that it is more natural to talk about an Exp-life, instead of a half-life, does anyone agree?

Comment: Nice question.  I suppose it would be a little bit nicer to work with mathematically.  But it's a little bit less natural for a human to think about a fraction $1/e$ than a fraction $1/2$.

Comment: Finding the time such that some exponential function falls to $1/e\approx 1/3$ of its original value is used all the time in physics. One usually doesn't call it an exp-life, though.

Comment: People talking about inflationary theories in cosmology talk all the time about e-folds.

Answer (score 1):

I like the following property - "exp-life" could as well stand for "expected life". Expected time before a given atom decays is indeed its exp-life. $$\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac t T}dt = T$$
But when you are interested in changes to overall quantity, half-life still seems easier to visualise.

Answer (score 0):

I teach half-life in calculus class, and it is pretty easy if you use this form of the equation:

$$y = P_0\left(\frac 12\right)^{t/h}$$

where $y$ and $P_0$ are the final and initial amounts, both with the same unit, $t$ is the elapsed time from time zero, and $h$ is the half-life, with the same unit as $t$.

The equation is easy to understand, ties directly in with half-life, and can be solved for $t$ by using logarithms to base one-half. Mainly, the students understand this clearly, before they learn about derivatives. After a while, I use this to show how natural logarithms can be used for any exponential equation.

I find this works well, better than some other approaches I tried. Its main weakness is in taking the derivative, which results in a more messy expression than if you use $e$ as the base. It still works well overall and seems more natural than an exp-life would be. I tried that concept once, without that particular name, and it did not work as well.

Comment: I thought about using base 2, however one half didn't cross my mind. Base one half will keep fractions out of the argument, right?

Comment: @Morph: My expression will keep fractions, as well as messy logarithms, out of the argument for many, but not all, problems. The easy problems will have easy solutions, while more difficult problems will have more difficult ones. An example of an easy problem: "Carbon 14 has a half-life of about 6,000 years. What would be the final amount be if 100 grams of Carbon 14 decays for 24,000 years?"